# Google Sign in and Backend Auth

Tags: php, reactjs, google-signin

I have followed a tutorial for Google Signin and it works fine Client-side. I have tried exporting the token server side but I keep getting a 500 Error which is being generated in my config.php file.  I have become muddled :/  If you can see what I am trying to do what am I missing?

config.php

```
<?php
//config.php
    session_start();
    require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    $google_client = new Google_Client();

    $google_client->setClientId($CLIENT_ID);
    $google_client->setClientSecret($CLIENT_SECRET);

    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $google_client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

    $google_client->addScope('email');
    $google_client->addScope('profile');

?>
```

createJSON.php

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
  if (isset($_POST['code'])) {
      $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_POST['code']);
    
 
    if(!isset($token['error'])){

      $google_client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);

      $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token['access_token'] ;

      $google_service = new Google_Service_0auth2($google_client);

      $data = $google_service->userinfo->get();

      if(!empty($data[email])){
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $data['email'];
      }

    }

  }
?>
```

I have the code below which is the landing page on successful login (I am using isSignedIn={true}) , which will use axios to start the Server Side Session, but I do not know what to send or even if I am doing it right?

All is working except when it hits the config.php file and the 500 error generates. [Code Updated from testing - now getting http://localhost/php/createJSON.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED]

```
 const responseGoogle = response => {       
            setName(response.profileObj.name);
            setUrl(response.profileObj.imageUrl);
            const postData = { code: response.tokenId };
            // Send a POST request                  
           axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:80/php/createJSON.php",
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            },
          //  headers: axiosConfig,
            data: postData
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('RESPONSE.DATA '+response.data);
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Comment: Where do `$CLIENT_ID` and `$CLIENT_SECRET` come from please

Comment: They are set to the correct Google Credentials :)

Comment: Not sure why it has been voted down for lack of research - I have explored the Google API, followed several tutorials and I am just stuck on this axios POST failing.  Note I have updated some of the code from testing today and currently I am getting http://localhost/php/createJSON.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED] when testing locally , 500 from the external server.

Comment: Did you check the error logs on the server?

Comment: Where is `$client` instantiated?

Comment: Cheers that should have been $google_client than you - Still getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228460/discussion-between-ozbodd-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED :)

I had a few issues:

1. Incorrect path for the Axios POST - Just needed the basic relative path
2. My config file simply needed the vendor path and CLIENT ID variable
3. I was not handling the JSON post, and now I have dropped in the code on Google https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth and all working :)

   $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
       $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($post['code']);
       if ($payload) {
         $userid = $payload['sub'];
         // If request specified a G Suite domain:
         //$domain = $payload['hd'];
         echo $payload['email'];
       } else {
         // Invalid ID token
         echo 'Failure';
       }
   ?>